# Why does sending formData with dio keeps sending instance of image path

Tags: flutter, dart, multipartform-data, mime-types, dio

I want to update profile details. I have name and an image field to put in the formData.
When I send the data this is the log of the Patch request
[log] ApiService - PATCH REQUEST DATA:: [MapEntry(fullName: Abunga Methoo), MapEntry(profilePic: Instance of 'Future')]

`try {

```
  final mimeTypeData =
      lookupMimeType(pickedImagePath.value, headerBytes: [0xFF, 0xD8])!
          .split('/');

  dio.FormData data = dio.FormData.fromMap(({
    "files": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
      pickedImagePath.value,
      filename: pickedImageName.value,
      contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]),
    ),
    'fullName': fullNameController.text
  }));
```

final result = await userService.updateProfile(payload: data);
I dont think i should be getting instance of file path as i am already awaiting the multifilePart. I am just tired already

`
this is the method for the formData.
i am expecting the log to come out with the user name and obviously the string of the filepath to be sent to the backend
but i keep getting instance of file path
see log::     [in this image is the code breakingpoint where i can see the file paht is down the trail, but at the top level is just its instance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB7a1.jpg)[log] ApiService - PATCH REQUEST DATA:: [MapEntry(fullName: Abunga Methoo), MapEntry(profilePic: Instance of 'Future')]

Comment: You can try instantiating below variable before creating data variable in dio.

 final partedfile = await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
      pickedImagePath.value,
      filename: pickedImageName.value,
      contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]),
    )
Then use it in fromMap method: 
"files": partedFile

Comment: this is what you are talking about?

      final partedfile = await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
        pickedImagePath.value,
        filename: pickedImageName.value,
        contentType: MediaType(mimeTypeData[0], mimeTypeData[1]),
      );

      dio.FormData data = dio.FormData.fromMap(({
        "files":  partedfile,
        'fullName': fullNameController.text
      }));
same response.  
MapEntry (MapEntry(files: Instance of 'MultipartFile'))